# how to clip a 3dtile in Cesium.js using polygon

Tags: javascript, 3d, cesiumjs

I have come across a problem that is difficult for me.I want to perform an operation that clip a 3dtile in cesium using a polygon. The question puzzled me for many days.I didn't find the answer I was looking for in many forums. I need you help, thanks!!
I tried this "tileset.clippingPlanes = createClippingPlanes(Cesium, coordinatesDegrees, tileset)", but it reported an error that is "Rendering has stopped.TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_target')"

```
function getInverseTransform (Cesium, tileset){
 let transform
 const tmp = tileset.root.transform
 if ((tmp && tmp.equals(Cesium.Matrix4.IDENTIFY)) || !tmp) {
 const center = tileset.boundingSphere.center
 transform = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(center )
 } else {
 transform = Cesium.Matrix4.fromArray(tileset.root.transform)
 }
 const martrix4 = new Cesium.Matrix4()
 return Cesium.Matrix4.inverseTransformation(transform, martrix4)
}

functi createClippingPlanes (Cesium, positions, tileset) {
 const clippingPlanes = []
 const inverseTransform = getInverseTransform(Cesium, tileset)
 const length = positions.length
 for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  const nextIndex = (i + 1) % length 
  const next = Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(inverseTransform, 
  positions[nextIndex], new Cesium.Cartesian3())
  const now = Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(inverseTransform, 
  positions[i], new Cesium.Cartesian3())

  const up = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 0, 10)

  let right = Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(next, now, new 
  Cesium.Cartesian3())
  right = Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(right, right)

  const normal = Cesium.Cartesian3.cross(right, up, new 
  Cesium.Cartesian3())
  Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(normal, normal)

  const planeTmp = Cesium.Plane.fromPointNormal(now, normal)
  const clipPlane = Cesium.ClippingPlane.fromPlane(planeTmp)
  clippingPlanes.push(clipPlane)
 }
 const clipPlanes = new Cesium.ClippingPlaneCollection({
  planes: clippingPlanes,
  edgeWidth: 1,
  edgeColor: Cesium.Color.white,
  enabled: true
 })
 return clipPlanes
}
```

Comment: I think the feature you're looking for is called "Clipping Planes."  https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=3D%20Tiles%20Clipping%20Planes.html

Comment: I reedited my question. Could you take a look at it for me ?